# Downloading only some email headers from Gmail 'sent items' with imap

Tags: delphi, gmail, imap

With regard to my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376704/get-email-headers-from-gmails-sent-items-folder) about accessing the 'sent items' folder in Gmail, the code presented in the accepted answer downloads **all** the message headers in the folder, using UIDRetrieveAllEnvelopes to do so. I filter the headers once they have all been downloaded.

Is there a way of downloading *only* the messages which have been sent in the current day (ie filtering before downloading)?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to retrieve only the messages of a certain day in a certain folder.

The IMAP way is to cache the message/envelope and only retrieve the recent/new messages.
Have a look at `TIdIMAP4.StatusMailbox` and `TIdIMAP4.RetrieveFlags` to examine, what messages are new to the client and download only those messages/enelopes.

Possible Flags are

```
  TIdMessageFlags =
  ( mfAnswered, //Message has been answered.
    mfFlagged, //Message is "flagged" for urgent/special attention.
    mfDeleted, //Message is "deleted" for removal by later EXPUNGE.
    mfDraft, //Message has not completed composition (marked as a draft).
    mfSeen, //Message has been read.
    mfRecent ); //Message is "recently" arrived in this mailbox.
```

Comment: I would prefer to use a [`mailbox search`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13612968/960757). Just instead of `skBody` search key with `Text` field I'd use the `skSentSince` key passing today's date to the `TIdIMAP4SearchRec.Date` field.

Comment: @TLama +1 - but AFAIK this is not limited to a special folder

Comment: @TLama: A search is the correct answer. A search is confined to the currently selected mailbox. So simply select the "sent items" mailbox and then perform a search.

Comment: Some IMAP backends do support this directly via the IMAP `SEARCH UID` command.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a way

```
 today:= datetostr (date);
 with imap do
  begin
   Username:= 'whatever@gmail.com';
   Password:= ....;
   Connect;
   if SelectMailBox('[Gmail]/sent items') then
    begin
     i:= MailBox.TotalMsgs;
     retrieve (i, email);
     while datetostr (email.date) = today do
      begin
       lb.items.add (email.subject + ' ' + datetostr (email.date));
       dec (i);
       retrieve (i, email)
      end 
    end;
   Disconnect;
  end;
```